# Basis of cyclic $k[t]$-Module

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

On page 373 of Algebra: Chapter 0, Paolo Aluffi writes:

> Even before spelling out the result of applying Theorem 5.6, we can make use of its slogan version: every ﬁnitely generated module over a PID is a direct sum of cyclic modules. This tells us that we can understand all linear transformations of ﬁnite-dimensional vector spaces, up to similarity, if we understand the linear transformation given by multiplication by $t$ on a cyclic $k[t]$-module $V = \frac{k[t]}{(f(t))}$

And then he writes

> We choose the basis $1, t, ..., t^{n-1}$ of $V$ (cf. Proposition III.4.6)

Proposition III 4.6 states that $\frac{R[x]}{(f(x))} \equiv R^{\oplus d}$ (as abelian groups)

I can't understand what does it mean that $k[x]$-module has a basis,
being a Torsion (each element is linearly dependent in that case). Does Aluffi mean that the underlying $k$ vector space has a basis? And if so, how can we strictly prove, that isomorphism of $k[t]$-modules (which preserve vector space structure) induces an isomorphism of underlying vector spaces?

Comment: Yes they mean $k$-vector space basis. Basis as $k[t]$-module makes sense only for free $k[t]$ modules that is isomorphic to $k[t]\oplus \ldots \oplus k[t]$, not what you are considering here. An isomorphism of $k[t]$-modules is also an isomorphism of $k$-modules ie. of $k$ vector spaces. You should think to $k[t]$-modules as $k$-vector spaces together with a specified endomorphism $E$ giving an action of polynomials: $f(t)\cdot v = f(E)(v)$.

Comment: @reuns thank you!